# OpenGL: will it keep image on screen by itself?

Tags: opengl

Taking Windows as an example, when drawing graphics via GDI one must redraw the scene (+validate, etc.) each time WM_PAINT happens. This requirement is really noticeable because otherwise graphics are corrupted pretty easily.

However with OpenGL it seems that once the scene is displayed via swapping buffers it persists regardless what is done to the window. It may be a useful feature.

The question: is this behavior cross-platform and reliable? Or is this just a common but not mandatory driver characteristic that cannot be relied upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However with OpenGL it seems that once the scene is displayed via swapping buffers it persists regardless what is done to the window.

That's definitely not the case. After swapping the buffers the contents of the back buffer are undefined and the contents of the front buffer are subject to the same damages as things drawn with other methods.

> The question: is this behavior cross-platform and reliable?

I don't know what you mean, because the behavior you describe does not exist.

Comment: At least on several combinations of particular OS/hardware (which i have within reach) it _looks_ like front buffer of the OpenGL context is way "sturdier" than regular GDI context. Well, you answered my question.

Comment: @Cfyz: Maybe you're fooled by window compositing. In a composited window environment each window is drawn to its very own offscreen surface. If windows overlap on the visible screen they don't really interfer with obstructed windows. However when you resize a window, notably when you decrease and then re-increase the size without redrawing, you can see the effect very well.